# Registration with Endpoints Server FAILED (App Engine connected Android Project)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am new to Android programming and Google App Engine. I followed the below documentation to run a sample app which registers my device: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae

**When I run the app(on a device), I see the following:**

1)Registration with Google Cloud Messaging...SUCCEEDED!

2)Registration with Endpoints Server...FAILED!

Unable to register your device with your cloud endpoints server. Either your cloud endpoints server is not deployed to app engine, or your settings need to be changed to run against a local instance by setting LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to 'true' in CloudEndpointUtils.java

**I also checked the LogCat and see the following exception:**

01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831): Exception received when attempting to register with server
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /10.0.2.2 (port 8888) after 20000ms
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:159)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:872)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:76)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.(HttpConnection.java:50)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:316)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:311)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:290)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:240)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:81)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:964)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService.onRegistered(GCMIntentService.java:163)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.handleRegistration(GCMBaseIntentService.java:251)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService.onHandleIntent(GCMBaseIntentService.java:153)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
01-14 06:05:40.268: E/com.googlecloudproject.GCMIntentService(1831):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

**Can anyone suggest on when this exception occurs and why my device is not able to register with cloud end points?**

Comment: Are you testing against a deployed App Engine project or on the local server? If your project is deployed, change the line `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = true` to `LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN = false`.

Comment: I am testing locally, so I have my LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN set as true

Comment: I believe you are testing on a handset as opposed to using an emulator. Use an emulator; you'll skip a lot of hurdles. For starters, the address listed (10.0.2.2) is used by the emulator-your device won't recognise it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it by setting

```
LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL = "http://[myLocalIp]:8888"
```

where `myLocalIp` is your ipv4-address which you can find by opening `cmd.exe` from your start menu and writing `ipconfig`.

Make sure to edit the correct `SERVER_URL` string in `CloudEndpointUtils.java`. I think it uses `LOCAL_APP_ENGINE_SERVER_URL_FOR_ANDROID` by default.

For this to work i also had to change the run configurations for the backend project. In Eclipse: select the server project -> right click -> Run as -> Run Configurations. Select the Arguments pane and in Program Arguments, add `--address=0.0.0.0` in front of the `--port=8888`.

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting Registration with Endpoints Server FAILED

Comment: why we should add `--address=0.0.0.0`?

Comment: @user2227422 also please check if you have set the value of LOCAL_ANDROID_RUN to be true. I missed at first but later corrected. I know you have already corrected it as of now.