# How to access local host from android device using google app engine?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using `Android Studio` and trying to access `local host` from android device using `google app engine`.I followed this [link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-templates/tree/master/HelloEndpoints).Now what they have shown it is nicely working with `genymotion`.Now when i tried with android device it didn't work.I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116314/registration-with-endpoints-server-failed-app-engine-connected-android-project) and give this in my run configuration, in VM Args as 
   **--address=0.0.0.0**
But when i tried to run the backend server it gives me some error.

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
Unrecognized option: --address=0.0.0.0
```

Now i have my `SignUp` class where i am communicating with server.

```
public class SignUp_Endpoint_Communicator extends AsyncTask <Pair<Context, UserinfoModel>, Void, ResponseMessages> {
    private Context maincontext;
    private UserinfoModelApi userinfo_api;
    private UserinfoModel userdata;
    private manipulate_Signup ms;
    @Override
    protected ResponseMessages doInBackground(Pair<Context, UserinfoModel>... params) {
        if(userinfo_api == null) {  // Only do this once
            UserinfoModelApi.Builder builder = new UserinfoModelApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    //.setRootUrl("http://10.0.2.2:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setRootUrl("http://0.0.0.0:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
            // end options for devappserver

            userinfo_api = builder.build();
        }
        maincontext = params[0].first;
        userdata = params[0].second;

        try {
            ResponseMessages response = new ResponseMessages();
            response = userinfo_api.setUserInfo(userdata).execute();
            return response;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ResponseMessages response){
        ms = (manipulate_Signup) ((Activity) maincontext);
        ms.setResponseMessage(response);
    }

    public interface manipulate_Signup{
        public void setResponseMessage(ResponseMessages response);
    }
}
```

Is there any other thing i have to change to work it for android device??

Comment: why you are setting 0.0.0.0 address as your end point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on it .In `android studio` at first go to **Run->Edit Configuration->backend->VM Args** and then paste the code of where my local datatstore bin presents

```
-Ddatastore.backing_store=E:\datastore\local_db.bin
```

and the `IP address` for android device is the `ipaddress` of your `wifi`.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working in Android Studio by doing the following:

1. When creating your `Builder`, replace the default '10.0.2.2' IP address  for the 'rootUrl' with your local IP address (mine is 192.168.1.222 below).

E.g:

```
MyApi.Builder builder = new MyApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // options for running against local devappserver
                    // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
                    // - 192.168.1.222 is my machine's IP address on my local network.
                    // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
                    .setRootUrl("http://192.168.1.222:8080/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    });
```

2. Edit the Run Configuration for your Appengine backend module:

   - **Run->Edit Configurations**, select your AppEngine configuration.
   - Uncheck 'Synchronize with build.gradle configuration'.
   - Change the 'Server Address' to 0.0.0.0
3. Re-run your Appengine module.

I went round the houses a bit trying to get this to work, so I hope it saves someone else some time. Google's docs on this don't seem to make this obvious.

Answer (score -1):

You should be using 10.0.2.2 for localhost.. Maybe this link can help..
https://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

Comment: yes..I couldn't figure it out what will be the address acutally??

Comment: Isn't he asking to run it on real device, why ip address for emulator?

Comment: `An emulated device can not see your development machine or other emulator instances on the network. Instead, it sees only that it is connected through Ethernet to a router/firewall.

The virtual router for each instance manages the 10.0.2/24 network address space — all addresses managed by the router are in the form of 10.0.2.<xx>, where <xx> is a number`. Taken from developer docs . Please read the link before downvoting an answer..